# Visual studio using the wrong template function for chrono::duration division

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, c++-chrono

I was converting over some code to use the c++11 chrono library rather than using the ctime library, at least in part to get a better understanding on the chrono library. Most of it has gone great, except for trying to do division by two chrono::durations. I've reduced the offending code down to a simple example and it took me a while to figure out why it was giving me the error it is.

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    chrono::milliseconds tickLength(16);
    chrono::milliseconds futureDuration(200);

    auto numTicks = futureDuration / tickLength;
}
```

This should access the function

```
template<class _Rep1,
    class _Period1,
    class _Rep2,
    class _Period2> inline
    typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type
        operator/(
            const duration<_Rep1, _Period1>& _Left,
            const duration<_Rep2, _Period2>& _Right)
```

but instead appears to be trying to use

```
template<class _Rep1,
    class _Period1,
    class _Rep2> inline
    typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Rep2,
        typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type>::value
        && !_Is_duration<_Rep2>::value,
        duration<typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type, _Period1> >::type
        operator/(
            const duration<_Rep1, _Period1>& _Left,
            const _Rep2& _Right)
```

and thus is trying to determine a common type between milliseconds and long long. The compiler output is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Playground, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  playground.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\type_traits(1446): error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'std::chrono::milliseconds' to '__int64'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          c:\users\XXX\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\playground\playground\playground.cpp(9) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::common_type<__int64,std::chrono::milliseconds>' being compiled
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code?
Is this a visual studio issue?
Is this a c++11 standard issue?

Comment: An interim solution I'm using is simply to call futureDuration.count() and tickLength.count(), which works as long as they're both of the same type (which is functionally what the division operator does, converts them to the same type and then calls their count functions and divides them)

Comment: Is there an error in the body of the function?  Because both of them should have their signature substituted, and substitution failure (if shallow) should cause substitution failure rather than an error.  Can you include the actual error message, instead of just the part you thought was important?  If there are line numbers, what line they refer to could also be useful.

Comment: This is a bug in their library implementation which has been fixed in VS "14".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code compiles for me using clang/libc++.  And your description of what should be happening sounds right to me.  Further, if I print out `numTicks`, I get 12, which is 200/16 (integer division).

Sounds like a visual stdio bug to me.  I see nothing wrong with your code.